# PyImgui with Pyglet doubles keyboard input

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet, imgui

I'm currently learning to use PyImgui within a Pyglet application. Everything seems to be working so far but I'm stumped at why PyImgui doubles my numeric keyboard inputs.
Here's a sample of my code:

```
import pyglet
import imgui
import imgui.core
from imgui.integrations.pyglet import PygletRenderer


class UI:
    def __init__(self, window):
        imgui.create_context()
        self.renderer = PygletRenderer(window)
        self.impl = PygletRenderer(window)
        imgui.new_frame()  
        imgui.end_frame()

        # Window variables
        self.test_input = 0

    def render(self):
        imgui.render()
        self.impl.render(imgui.get_draw_data())
        imgui.new_frame()

        imgui.begin("Test Window")
        imgui.text("This is the test window.")
        changed, self.test_input = imgui.input_int("Integer Input Test", self.test_input)

        imgui.end()

        imgui.end_frame()


class App(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(800, 600, "Imgui Test")
        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/60)
        self.UI_test = UI(self)

    def on_draw(self):
        pass

    def update(self, dt):
        self.clear()
        self.UI_test.render()


app = App()
pyglet.app.run()
```

If I press 1 on my keyboard, the textbox shows 11. However, backspace inputs are not doubled and works as expected.
If I wanted to input 1500, I'd have to press 1 then backspace, 5 then backspace, and 0 once.

Is there something I'm missing or overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instantiated PygletRenderer twice.

Commenting out the first instance worked for me:

```
#self.renderer = PygletRenderer(window)
```

Thanks for posting this!  I just discovered pyimgui and this post gave me an example to start with! :)

Comment: Well that was kind of a stupid oversight, thank you very much. The solution has worked for me.